# How to get column name from column values in Ansible

Tags: csv, ansible

I have an csv file with follow structure:

```
aday       bday          cday
12-2-2021 12-2-2021      12-2-2021
13-3-2021 12-9-2021      13-1-2021
15-6-2021 12-9-2021      16-2-2021
```

I want to write an ansible play to print column name if the date matches with today's date have figured out the date matching logic but unable to get the respectecive column name of the date matched.

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"**Print column name if the date matches with today's date.**"*

A: Parse the data first. The module [read_csv](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/read_csv_module.html#community-general-read-csv-read-a-csv-file) won't parse this file because of the missing delimiter. Fix it, e.g.

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: test.csv
        regexp: '(\S)[^\S\n]+(\S)'
        replace: '\1;\2'
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat test.csv
aday;bday;cday
12-2-2021;12-2-2021;12-2-2021
13-3-2021;12-9-2021;13-1-2021
15-6-2021;12-9-2021;16-2-2021
```

Now, use *read_csv*, e.g.

```yaml
    - read_csv:
        path: test.csv
        delimiter: ';'
      register: days
    - debug:
        var: days
```

gives

```yaml
  days:
    changed: false
    dict: {}
    failed: false
    list:
    - aday: 12-2-2021
      bday: 12-2-2021
      cday: 12-2-2021
    - aday: 13-3-2021
      bday: 12-9-2021
      cday: 13-1-2021
    - aday: 15-6-2021
      bday: 12-9-2021
      cday: 16-2-2021
```

Create a dictionary with the columns

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        days_dict: "{{ days_dict|d({})|
                       combine({item: days.list|
                                      map(attribute=item)|
                                      list}) }}"
      loop: "{{ days.list.0.keys()|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  days_dict:
    aday:
    - 12-2-2021
    - 13-3-2021
    - 15-6-2021
    bday:
    - 12-2-2021
    - 12-9-2021
    - 12-9-2021
    cday:
    - 12-2-2021
    - 13-1-2021
    - 16-2-2021
```

Now, select columns which contain today's date, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        cols_today: "{{ cols_today|d([]) + [item.key] }}"
      loop: "{{ days_dict|dict2items }}"
      vars:
        today: '13-1-2021'
      when: today in item.value
```

gives

```yaml
  cols_today:
  - cday
```

The filter *json_query* gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        cols_today: "{{ days_dict|dict2items|json_query(my_query) }}"
      vars:
        today: '13-1-2021'
        my_query: "[?value.contains(@, '{{ today }}')].key"
```